# Custom element vs web component css encapsulation?

Tags: html, css

Do custom elements -- that do not use a shadow dom--  provide the same style encapsulation as web components (autonomous custom elements) that use a shadow dom?

The [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_components/Using_custom_elements) on using custom elements along with examples on [github](https://github.com/mdn/web-components-examples/tree/main) don't clearly say.

Comment: if they are placed in the regular DOM instead of the shadow DOM then they act normally as any other regular element.

Comment: @tacoshy so the custom part is about extending the behaviour of the custom element not encapsulation of the element?

Comment: the custom part is by using tags as elements that not regularilly exist. it was added mainly for applications.

Comment: I wish the documentation was more clear ... there are user-agent shadow roots, thought the custom css might be added to those.

Answer (score 0):

**No**, Custom Elements **without** shadowDOM are DOM elements just like any other `<div>` or `<p>` or any Element.

Only `shadowRoots` provide scope for CSS (or `id` attributes for that matter)
Which you can style, **from outside the component**, with:

- CSS properties
- ::part
- theme

##### Web Components are *distinct* technologies

- Templates
- Custom Elements
- shadowDOM

**each can be used WITHOUT the other**

You **can apply** a shadowRoot to a **regular** DOM element:

`document.querySelector("DIV").attachShadow({mode:"open"})`

This **does not** make them a **Custom Element**, but does provide scoped CSS

You only add shadowDOM when you need it. (alas many libraries force shadowDOM on you)

Also note you are totally free to make up any tags your want.

```
<pie-chart>
  <slice size="90" stroke="green">HTML</slice>
  <slice size="1"  stroke="red">JavaScript</slice>
  <slice size="9"  stroke="blue">CSS</slice>
</pie-chart>
```

`<pie-chart>` is a Web Component/Custom Element, and `<slice>` **is not** (and can not be).

[image]

See my DEV.to blogsposts:

- https://dev.to/dannyengelman/what-web-technologies-are-required-to-draw-a-pie-chart-in-2021-spoiler-alert-a-standard-web-component-will-do-1j56
- https://dev.to/dannyengelman/web-components-using-unknownhtmlelements-for-better-semantic-html-5d8c

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253859/discussion-on-answer-by-danny-365csi-engelman-custom-element-vs-web-component); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.